# MapServer map file shows Raster image as white

Tags: raster, mapserver, mapfile

I'm using PAN image for raster publishing but the output in browser shows a full white image? Please give me the solution?
My map file is ass follows:

```
MAP
NAME "terra"
# Map image size
SIZE 600 600
UNITS dd
EXTENT 77.0962025047 23.8718740333 84.6389301196 30.4075924299
  PROJECTION
   'proj=longlat'
   'ellps=WGS84'
   'datum=WGS84'
   'no_defs'
  END
  # Background color for the map canvas -- change as desired
  IMAGECOLOR 155 155 155
  IMAGEQUALITY 95
  IMAGETYPE png

  OUTPUTFORMAT
   NAME png
   DRIVER 'GD/PNG'
   MIMETYPE 'image/png'
   IMAGEMODE RGBA
   EXTENSION 'png'
  END
  # Legend
  LEGEND
      IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
    STATUS ON
    KEYSIZE 18 12
    LABEL
      TYPE BITMAP
      SIZE MEDIUM
      COLOR 0 0 0
    END
  END

  # Web interface definition. Only the template parameter
  # is required to display a map. See MapServer documentation
  WEB
    # Set IMAGEPATH to the path where MapServer should
    # write its output.
    IMAGEPATH "../tmp"

    # Set IMAGEURL to the url that points to IMAGEPATH
    # as defined in your web server configuration
    IMAGEPATH "../tmp"

    # WMS server settings
    METADATA
      'wms_title'           'terra'
      'wms_onlineresource'  'http://my.host.com/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=wms.map&'
      'wms_srs'             'EPSG:4326'
    END

    #Scale range at which web interface will operate
    # Template and header/footer settings
    # Only the template parameter is required to display a map. See MapServer documentation
  END
  LAYER
    NAME "UPC1PAN10SISDP2012"
    TYPE RASTER
    OFFSITE 0 0 0
    DATA 'Z:\Rasters\10K\10D\UP\UPC1PAN10SISDP2012.img '
    METADATA
      'wms_title' 'UPC1PAN10SISDP2012'
      'WMS_ENABLE_REQUEST' '*'
    END
    STATUS DEFAULT
    TRANSPARENCY 100
    PROJECTION
    'proj=longlat'
    'ellps=WGS84'
    'datum=WGS84'
    'no_defs'
 ''
    END
  END

END
```

Comment: `TRANSPARENCY 100`makes the layer totally transparent.

Comment: my out put showing black dotted boarder and remaining inside white....

Comment: There may be something else wrong too but if you do not correct the transparency you will never get it right. Did you already correct it?

Comment: ya i correct it....even image showing in white color but back ground color of image is as desired myself

Comment: Add gdalinfo report about Z:\Rasters\10K\10D\UP\UPC1PAN10SISDP2012.img into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options 1) if input data is 16 bit convert into 8 bit data. 2)By placing PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
as follow

```
 MAP
NAME "terra"
# Map image size
SIZE 600 600
UNITS dd
EXTENT 77.0962025047 23.8718740333 84.6389301196 30.4075924299
  PROJECTION
   'proj=longlat'
   'ellps=WGS84'
   'datum=WGS84'
   'no_defs'
  END
  # Background color for the map canvas -- change as desired
  IMAGECOLOR 155 155 155
  IMAGEQUALITY 95
  IMAGETYPE png

  OUTPUTFORMAT
   NAME png
   DRIVER 'GD/PNG'
   MIMETYPE 'image/png'
   IMAGEMODE RGBA
   EXTENSION 'png'
  END
  # Legend
  LEGEND
      IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
    STATUS ON
    KEYSIZE 18 12
    LABEL
      TYPE BITMAP
      SIZE MEDIUM
      COLOR 0 0 0
    END
  END

  # Web interface definition. Only the template parameter
  # is required to display a map. See MapServer documentation
  WEB
    # Set IMAGEPATH to the path where MapServer should
    # write its output.
    IMAGEPATH "../tmp"

    # Set IMAGEURL to the url that points to IMAGEPATH
    # as defined in your web server configuration
    IMAGEPATH "../tmp"

    # WMS server settings
    METADATA
      'wms_title'           'terra'
      'wms_onlineresource'  'http://my.host.com/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=wms.map&'
      'wms_srs'             'EPSG:4326'
    END

    #Scale range at which web interface will operate
    # Template and header/footer settings
    # Only the template parameter is required to display a map. See MapServer documentation
  END
  LAYER
    NAME "UPC1PAN10SISDP2012"
    TYPE RASTER
    PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
    OFFSITE 0 0 0
    DATA 'Z:\Rasters\10K\10D\UP\UPC1PAN10SISDP2012.img '
    METADATA
      'wms_title' 'UPC1PAN10SISDP2012'
      'WMS_ENABLE_REQUEST' '*'
    END
    STATUS DEFAULT
    TRANSPARENCY 100
    PROJECTION
    'proj=longlat'
    'ellps=WGS84'
    'datum=WGS84'
    'no_defs'
 ''
    END
  END

END
```

Comment: It is usefull..